# AngularJS: custom $resource actions don't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm trying to define a custom getUsers action to a $resource, but I get an error that the object has no getUsers method.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('Customer', ['$resource', 'apiUrl', function ($resource, apiUrl) {
        return $resource(apiUrl + '/customers/:id', {
            query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            get: {method: 'GET'},
            getUsers: {method: 'GET', url: apiUrl + '/customers/:id/users', isArray: true}
        });
    }]);
```

Using it with `Customer.getUsers({id: 'id'})`

I'm using 1.2.0-rc2. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('Customer', ['$resource', 'apiUrl', function ($resource, apiUrl) {
    return $resource(apiUrl + '/customers/:id', {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        get: {method: 'GET'},
        getUsers: {method: 'GET', url: apiUrl + '/customers/:id/users', isArray: true}
    });
}]);
```

Replace To:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('Customer', ['$resource', 'apiUrl', function ($resource, apiUrl) {
     return $resource(apiUrl + '/customers/:id', { id: 'id' }, { //here add { }
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        get: {method: 'GET'},
        getUsers: {method: 'GET', url: apiUrl + '/customers/:id/users', isArray: true}
    });
}]);
```